# How to access wampserver 2.5 localhost in LAN

Tags: wamp

I have a windows 10 PC with wampserver 2.5 and I want to access it on my phone. I can get to 192.168.22.3/phpmyadmin using my mobile phone but not in localhost or any other vhosts like 192.168.22.3/wordpress. I have already edited the

```
#    offlineonline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
Require ip 192.168.22
```

and I still get the 403 Forbidden on my mobile when accessing 192.168.22.3/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If your server is, for example, 192.168.1.254 and you want access from, for example, 192.168.1.5 or everywhere like public IPs or free dns services, you have to edit the file **c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf** and change

```
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
```

in

```
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require all granted
  </IfDefine>
```

my file:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside  
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require all granted
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
     Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```